# Display order of Elements in a Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got 3 elements (#hotlink1Div, #topBarContentid, #hotlink2Div) which will be in a loop.

I have managed to find the code to get the loop online.
Currently the order in which they are appearing is: #topBarContentid, #hotlink1Div, #hotlink2Div

I would like to see the following order: #topBarContentid, #hotlink1Div, #topBarContentid, #hotlink2Div, #topBarContentid.

```
slideHotlinks: function () {
    console.log(this.px + "Hotlinks started");
    var $elements = $('#hotlink1Div, #topBarContentid, #hotlink2Div');      //List of elements used
    function hotlinks_loop(index) {                         //Function to index elements as their are shown
        console.log(this.px + "Hotlinks loop created");
        $elements.eq(index).slideDown(1000, function() {
            var $self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log(this.px + "Hotlinks timeout set");
                $self.fadeOut(1000);
                hotlinks_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length);
            },5000);
    });
}
hotlinks_loop(0); // start with the first element
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing with your code? It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/aVsE2/

Comment: I have created a demo here: http://jsbin.com/uwonun/42/

Current order being displayed is pointsbar, hotlink1 and hotlink2.

I would like to have pointsbar, hotlink1, pointsbar, hotlink2, pointsbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
var elements = ['#pointsbarDiv', '#hotlink1Div','#pointsbarDiv', '#hotlink2Div'];

function anim_loop(index) {
    $(elements[index]).slideDown(1000, function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $self.fadeOut(1000);
            anim_loop((index + 1) % elements.length);
        }, 5000);
    });
}

anim_loop(0); // start with the first element
```

Taken from an edit of the original jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uwonun/46

This uses a javascript array rather than a jquery selector. Each entry in the array is converted into a jquery object in the first line of the `anim_loop` function.

A jquery selector is not quite the same thing as a collection, instead it walks the dom of the page and returns elements that match it's expression, in the order they appear on the page. Therefore it is not possible to get a selector to return the same element twice. In addition id's within a page should be unique, so a selector should only return one element for each id.

Comment: I think that's a good approach.  jQuery probably always returns selections in document order.

Comment: I was too slow, but this is pretty much the same as I was going to post. [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zRQ5d/) incase its useful to the OP.